# Partitioning Related Rows into Groups

Tags: t-sql

I have some legacy product data that has proven difficult to work with.  The products can be sold with 1, 2 or 3 parts, and the way the system was designed, parts 2 and 3 for an ordered product were simply subsequent rows after the first row for that product.

Here is some sample data....

```
----------------------------------------------------------
OrderId     Sku     Type     Row_Id   OtherColumns...
----------------------------------------------------------
123         001     Double   0        Other stuff..
123         001     Double   1        Other stuff..
123         001     Double   2        Other stuff..
123         001     Double   3        Other stuff..
123         002     Single   4        Other stuff..
123         003     Triple   5        Other stuff..
123         003     Triple   6        Other stuff..
123         003     Triple   7        Other stuff..
123         001     Double   8        Other stuff..
123         001     Double   9        Other stuff..
123         002     Single   10        Other stuff..
123         002     Single   11        Other stuff..
123         002     Single   12        Other stuff..
123         002     Single   13        Other stuff..
```

The old software (VB) deals with this by iterating over the rows and looking forward as it loops, getting the information it needs from the rows, and then skips them.

Fast forward 8 years...I have inherited this system in my new job and have rewritten the system from the ground up.  The problem I'm having is getting that legacy data into my new format.

I'm looking for a way to select the same data, and partition it by the appropriate segment numbers.  I've used RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY) with no success.  I think I'm just not doing it right.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to generate a result set that looks like this: (NOTE the Segment column)

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
OrderId     Sku     Type     Row_Id     Segment   OtherColumns...
-------------------------------------------------------------------
123         001     Double   0          1         Other stuff..
123         001     Double   1          2         Other stuff..
123         001     Double   2          1         Other stuff..
123         001     Double   3          2         Other stuff..
123         002     Single   4          1         Other stuff..
123         003     Triple   5          1         Other stuff..
123         003     Triple   6          2         Other stuff..
123         003     Triple   7          3         Other stuff..
123         001     Double   8          1         Other stuff..
123         001     Double   9          2         Other stuff..
123         002     Single   10         1         Other stuff..
123         002     Single   11         1         Other stuff..
123         002     Single   12         1         Other stuff..
123         002     Single   13         1         Other stuff..
```

Ideally, I'd like to avoid cursors or loops.  I'll be using the query to migrate millions of records that are derived from multiple tables.

Thanks in advance for your help.

**EDIT**
I've updated the sample data to show that I do indeed have back to back groups that I need to isolate.

Comment: The identifier for a 'group' is only the `Type` column, where a 'double' value means two rows grouped, & 'triple' means three? And - shouldn't you create an identifier which is distinct among groups, rather than a 'segment' that doesn't seem to group the rows at all?

Comment: The second example table is not my new format...it's simply a resultset for me to easily identify segments for my data import process.

Comment: Ok. And the first part of my question?

Comment: Correct on the first question.  If it is Single, only that row matters.  If it is Double, that row and the next matter.  For Triple, that row and the following two matter.  Make sense?   I about died when I first saw how they did this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select OrderId,
       Sku,
       Type,
       Row_Id,
       (row_number() over(partition by Type order by Row_Id) - 1) %
        case Type
          when 'Single' then 1
          when 'Double' then 2
          when 'Triple' then 3
        end + 1
from YourTable
order by Row_Id
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e38d3/3)

Comment: That's awesome.  Unfortunately I'm not on 2012.

Comment: @ctorx - Clearly you should be :)

Comment: @ctorx - Performance on the second version should not be all that bad if you have an index on `Row_Id` with `Type` as an include column.

Comment: I'm getting some success with this, but it is not consistent.  I updated my question to show that I do have back to back groups...not sure if this query handles that correctly, though the outer apply row_id checks and desc order seems like it would...

Comment: @ctorx - Back to the drawing board and a totally new idea. I have updated my answer.

Comment: This is just brilliant. Too bad I've already spent my vote on your previous version. (Maybe you should have posted this as a new answer.)

Comment: @AndriyM - I take your vote for this one instead :). This is so much better.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant.   I was headed down this path but didn't think to mod on a case statement.  Thanks, you have saved me a great deal of headache.